# Clera Redis Cache pool: How to change namespace

Tags: symfony, redis

I'm trying to clear redis cache via command line : `bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.my_redis`

1/ I created a custom provider as already mentioned under the doc: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/cache.html#custom-provider-options

```
app.my_custom_redis_provider:
    class: \Redis
    factory: ['Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter', 'createConnection']
    arguments:
        - 'redis://redis:6379'
```

2/ I configured my framework cache key:

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: app.my_custom_redis_provider
        pools:
            cache.my_redis:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                provider: app.my_custom_redis_provider
```

After executing `bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.my_redis` the cache is notreally cleared.
I get: `Clearing cache pool: cache.my_redis  => Cache was successfully cleared` But when I verify my redis storage, nothing is cleared, and it show me these keys:

```
PHPREDIS_SESSION_o5lpfttunv4r6sfsiktr046s1m
sf_sfmagu8rpbsmm3oplmhnuhl9slp
```

Comment: What happened when you specify the environment? `--env=dev`

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant I updated the question, same thing, Clearing cache pool: cache.my_redis  => Cache was successfully cleared But when I verify my redis storage, nothing is cleared.